# Getting the MatBottomSheet to be flush against the top toolbar?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

If we want the `MatBottomSheet` to popup so that the top of it is flush against the top toolbar, what's the best way to achieve this?  This is the demo from the documentation.

https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/examples

[In this stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matbottomsheet-demo-with-styling) I'm assuming that the top toolbar is 40px in height.  Thus I set the `height` of the `HelloComponent` displayed by the `MatBottomSheet`  `100%` and the top margin to `40px`, which should keep it from overlapping with the toolbar however the sheet this did not work out quite right.

How do we style the `MatBottomSheet` container?  I also tried:

```
.mat-bottom-sheet-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

I think this will work:

```
.mat-bottom-sheet-container {
  min-height: vh;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Anyone know why `min-height: 100%` does not work?

Comment: Seems excessive from a UX perspective.  If I'm understanding correctly, you want the _bottom_ sheet to extend to the top of the page, minus the navbar height?  Wouldn't be much of a bottom sheet then.

Comment: I plan on putting search results in it.  So that when the user clicks on the search field and starts typing the search results overlay the rest of the application.

Comment: Can you share a mockup of what you intend?  I kinda see what you're getting at but it still seems un-intuitive... i.e. the Chrome search flows top-down. Is your search bar at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: The search fields will be embedded in the top toolbar - like it is here on SO.  When the user clicks in it and starts typing the search results will show in the MatBottomSheet which will popup.  The current stackblitz demo is a pretty good approximation, except it's missing the search field ATM (Only has a button trigger).

Comment: Just realized that it's not going to work ... that well ... because the typing in the search cannot happen at the same time that the `MatButtonSheet` is showing ... as it disabled the search field in the toolbar ...

Answer (score 0):

If the height is to be taken 100 percent leaving the top navigation bar of 40 px you can try this css

```
.mat-bottom-sheet-container {
  height: calc(100%-40px);
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Use the calc function it will always adjust to 100% height leaving yoir 40px for top navigation bar

Comment: Looks good, but no dice unfortunately: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matbottomsheet-demo-with-styling-pbzx62?file=src/styles.css